# Trying to figure out how to Grab part of a table. (hard to explain fully)

Tags: lua, lua-table, fivem

So, what i am trying to do is... well it's best to show.
Also, this is about FiveM and I'm trying to modify an existing resource.

```
BMProducts = {
{
["lostItems"] = {
[1] = { name = "weapon_shotgun", price = 1500, crypto = 2500, amount = 1 },
},
}
}

table.insert(BMProducts, {
["ballasItems"] = {
[1] = { name = "weapon_pistol", price = 1500, crypto = 2500, amount = 1 },
},
})

Config.Products = BMProducts
```

And I have a another config, that I need to pull the Correct table, but now sure entirely how

```
["products"] =  Config.Products["ballasItems"],
```

Is what I have but it won't read it, due to what I assume is what i saw when debugging, that when inserting to the table, it assigns a number, ie;

```
[1] = {lostitems = {...
[2] = {ballasItems = {...
```

One that works, but what my ultimate goal is to make the code plug and play with the table inserts, is this

```
BMProducts = 
{
["lostItems"] = {
[1] = { name = "weapon_pistol", price = 1500, crypto = 2500, amount = 1 },
},
["ballasItems"] = {
[1] = { name = "weapon_pistol", price = 1500, crypto = 2500, amount = 1 },
},
}
```

which works with the config above because the way just above does not assign numbers and not inserting into a table. Any ideas how i can go about setting that config for the correct Products table?

When i try it with the table insert, and with the

```
["products"] =  Config.Products["ballasItems"],
```

It can't find the table, which is due to what i assume the table format being different than what it was, which was the code block at the bottom

so my main thing, is to get

```
["products"] =  Config.Products["ballasItems"],
```

to = the correct table when there is a table insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to table.insert, then don't table.insert:

```lua
BMProducts["ballasItems"] = {
    { name = "weapon_pistol", price = 1500, crypto = 2500, amount = 1 },
}
```

Now I think you told to not modify the config, so another approach is to just use that additional array index when indexing:

```lua
["products"] = Config.Products[2]["ballasItems"]
```

Which obviously assumes that the config never changes and the entry with `ballasItems` is on index 2.

If you do not know the index, you may want to iterate over `Config.Products` and look for the right product.

```lua
for i,v in ipairs(Config.Products) do
    if v["ballasItems"] then

    end
end
```

You may also consider the case where two or more products match.

Comment: The issue is that i want to do a Table insert, For example the lostItems is in one file, and the ballasItems is in another file. There is quite a bit of code that i don't have shown, but if there are multiple locations, set as 

    `Config.Locations = {
    ["lost"] = {
    ["products"] = "ballasItems"
    }
    }`

Trying to get a loop that will find the correct table based off ["products"]

Comment: And as you said
`["products"] = Config.Products[2]["ballasItems"]`
Would work if the config never changed, but if i want to make it modular by inserting tables, then it would not work.

Comment: But what's about the loop I've shown you?